# no viable alternative at input at CREATE TABLE with column defined as MAP<INT,<ARRAY<MAP<INT,FLOAT>>>>

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am running the following spark query

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS hmi_feature_array;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hmi_feature_array (
    cycle_timestamp BIGINT,
    campaign_id BIGINT,
    arm ARRAY<BIGINT>,
    context_feature MAP<INT,<ARRAY<MAP<INT,FLOAT>>>>
)
PARTITIONED BY(ds STRING)
TBLPROPERTIES (
    'RETENTION' = '90',
    'noUII' = '1'
);
```

However, I am getting getting the error `no viable alternative at input` at `context_feature MAP<INT,<ARRAY<MAP<INT,FLOAT>>>>`. The full relevant error log is the following :

`[INFO    ][1479233][2022-08-23 15:44:33,685][MainThread][utils.py:514             ]- Logging Spark App Metrics to XDB through wrapper: Sample(<class 'dict'>, {'normal': {'exception': "org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: \nno viable alternative at input 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hmi_feature_array (\\n    cycle_timestamp BIGINT,\\n    campaign_id BIGINT,\\n    arm ARRAY<BIGINT>,\\n    context_feature MAP<INT,<'(line 5, pos 28)\n\n== SQL ==\nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hmi_feature_array (\n    cycle_timestamp BIGINT,\n    campaign_id BIGINT,\n    arm ARRAY<BIGINT>,\n    context_feature MAP<INT,<ARRAY<MAP<INT,FLOAT>>>>\n----------------------------^^^\n)\nPARTITIONED BY(ds STRING)\nTBLPROPERTIES`

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out instead of `context_feature MAP<INT,<ARRAY<MAP<INT,FLOAT>>>>` it should have been `context_feature MAP<INT,ARRAY<MAP<INT,FLOAT>>>`. Basically `<>` is not needed around `ARRAY`.